# emulator output different from layout view in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-emulator

In the layout view my calculator program looks like this
[image]

But when I run my program, it looks like this

[image]

Why is this happening?

This is the layout file code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/button_0"
        android:onClick="onClkBn0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_dot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button0"
        android:text="@string/button_dot" 
        android:onClick="onClkBnDot"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_res"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_dot"
        android:text="@string/button_res" 
        android:onClick="onClkBnRes"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button0"
        android:text="@string/button_1" 
        android:onClick="onClkBn1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_dot"
        android:text="@string/button_2" 
        android:onClick="onClkBn2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_res"
        android:text="@string/button_3" 
        android:onClick="onClkBn3"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/button_4" 
        android:onClick="onClkBn4"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:text="@string/button_5" 
        android:onClick="onClkBn5"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:text="@string/button_6" 
        android:onClick="onClkBn6"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:text="@string/button_7" 
        android:onClick="onClkBn7"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:text="@string/button_8" 
        android:onClick="onClkBn8"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
        android:text="@string/button_9" 
        android:onClick="onClkBn9"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_res"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_res"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_res"
        android:text="@string/button_plus" 
        android:onClick="onClkBnPlus"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_minus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_plus"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_plus"
        android:text="@string/button_minus" 
        android:onClick="onClkBnMinus"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_mul"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_minus"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
        android:text="@string/button_mult" 
        android:onClick="onClkBnMult"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_div"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_mul"
        android:text="@string/button_div" 
        android:onClick="onClkBnDiv"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_can"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_div"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/button_cancel" 
        android:onClick="onClkBnCan"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mantissa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_can"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/mantissa_default"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="30.0sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_off"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mantissa"
        android:layout_above = "@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_can"
        android:onClick="onClkBnOff"
        android:text="@string/button_off" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you check how wider your emulator screen and your device screen? I think there is difference of width there. You should check that.

Comment: I am only doing this on emulator

Comment: the difference is between the emulator screen and the design view; it looks as I want it to look on the design view, but looks different on the emulator output

Comment: That is why I am asking you, first check what is your screen density and width. Either with code or explicitly get that.

Comment: How can I find out? In AVD the device is Galaxy Nexus (4.65", 720 * 1280:xhdpi) and if I go to Details... then it says hw.lcd.density: 320

Comment: In your Button C try to set the property  `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and then check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your emulator is doing what you ask.  This code :

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

puts the "c" button in the middle of the view, vertically.  Then your mantissa view sits atop that view because of this:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/button_can"
```

Your off button is coerced into stretching from the mantissa view down to button_9 because of these lines:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/mantissa"
android:layout_above = "@+id/button9"
```

Here is one solution that should work for you:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_can"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/button_div"
    android:layout_above="@id/button_div"
    android:text="@string/button_cancel" 
    android:onClick="onClkBnCan"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mantissa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/button_can"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/mantissa_default"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="30.0sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_off"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above = "@id/button9"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button9"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_can"
    android:onClick="onClkBnOff"
    android:text="@string/button_off" />
```

Also, you should only use the + in strings like `"@+id/button9"` on the first use of that label.  Subsequent references for it would be `"@id/button9"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should better use a couple of [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) to get the aspect you want.

Thanks to [android:layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_weight) you will be able to have the same layout aspect on several screen sizes and density.

Here is a code example showing what you want, the way you want on several screen sizes/devices density:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mantissa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/mantissa_default"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="30.0sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mantissa"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_off"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBnOff"
            android:text="@string/button_off" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_can"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBnCan"
            android:text="@string/button_cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBn7"
            android:text="@string/button_7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBn8"
            android:text="@string/button_8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBn9"
            android:text="@string/button_9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_div"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBnDiv"
            android:text="@string/button_div" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBn4"
            android:text="@string/button_4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBn5"
            android:text="@string/button_5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBn6"
            android:text="@string/button_6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_mul"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBnMult"
            android:text="@string/button_mult" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button0"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBn1"
            android:text="@string/button_1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button_dot"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBn2"
            android:text="@string/button_2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBn3"
            android:text="@string/button_3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_minus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBnMinus"
            android:text="@string/button_minus" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBn0"
            android:text="@string/button_0"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_dot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBnDot"
            android:text="@string/button_dot" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_res"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBnRes"
            android:text="@string/button_res"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_plus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:onClick="onClkBnPlus"
            android:text="@string/button_plus" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```